# Delphi Syntax for TextMate

Tags: delphi, syntax, textmate, pascal, oxygene

I exchanged emails with Marc-André Cournoyer of [RefactorMyCode.com](http://RefactorMyCode.com/) about supporting Delphi on his site.  Since his site uses [Ruby's UltraViolet](http://ultraviolet.rubyforge.org/) to do syntax highlighting, and it uses [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) syntaxes, he needs a Delphi syntax for TextMate.  Turns out it has a [Pascal syntax](http://macromates.com/svn/Bundles/trunk/Bundles/Pascal.tmbundle/) already, so it is 90% of the way there.

Does anyone know where I might find one that has already been updated for Delphi?  A Delphi Prism / Oxygene one would be great too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official delphi syntax. I was busy compiling one, but had some family problems that took most of my time. I'm going to continue the effort next week and expect to be finished by the end of the week.

See also: [looking for a complete delphi object pascal syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171827/looking-for-a-complete-delphi-object-pascal-syntax)

Comment: Yeah, I remember your question.  It would be a good resource to build one for TextMate.  I am specifically looking for a syntax for TextMade.